# Heroku Preboot Rollover Time

Tags: heroku, deployment

We use Heroku's preboot lab to get us zero downtime deploys. As our infrastructure has grown more complex, we have started to get several different apps which need to have deploys coordinated. Preboot seems to be set for approximately 3 minutes. Is there any env variable or configuration we can use to change this duration? I would like to have it between 1-2 minutes for one of our applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  There is currently no customization of `preboot`.

It's a labs feature that can only be turned on or off.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-preboot